# Postgres on Mac - psql runs automatically

Tags: macos, bash, postgresql

I installed postgres recently using the postgres mac app. Now every time i start a new terminal (bash), it triggers and starts psql on the terminal. I'm not able to find the place where this is configured.
This is not part of `.bashrc or .bash_profile` for sure. So it only happens if I start new terminal tab, not if I source bash_profile/rc

Nothing in `terminal > preferences > startup script`.
I'm clueless!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OBSELETE** open this file :  `Library/LaunchDaemons/com.edb.launchd.postgresql-9.0.plist`(change 9.0 to your version number)

**EDIT** for 9.4.4 (open or create this file instead) : `~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.postgresql.postgres.plist`.
Then, follow the steps in the section called automatically Start the Server at Boot from this [blog post](http://mac-dev-env.patrickbougie.com/postgresql/).

after the line : `<key>RunAtLoad</key>`

replace `<true/> to <false/>`

save your file then restart the terminal and it should work

Comment: sorry no such file exist!

Comment: edited my answer with a working solution for 9.4.4 ! just follow the steps from the blog post I linked to

Comment: ahh interesting. I think it was triggered from another script. I actually went ahead and disabled a bunch of things from LaunchDaemons and the problem is not occurring anymore. Thanks